# Substitute values in sympy vector

Tags: function, numpy, vector, eval, sympy

I have 1000 parameters vector valued function, f( s,t,w,v,q,....) which needs to be evaluated at certain values of s,t,w,v,q,..... = 2, 3, 6,....

Is there a way to substitute parameter_vector = [ s, t, w, v, q, ..] by parameter_values = [2, 3, 6,...] into f_vector = [s+t, s, ...]

I have added 10 paramters in the sample code. I am using [sympy](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/index.html) because f_vector is itself output from derivative or differentiation of other function, and the derivative ahs been done by sympy.

```
s,t,v,w,q,e,r,m,b,a = sym.symbols ('s,t,v,w,q,e,r,m,b,a')
f_vector = [ s+t, s, v-2, w-a, q, r, e, a-7, b-m, t  ]
parameter_vector = ([ s,t,v,w,q,e,r,m,b,a ])
parameter_values_vector =[ 2,3,6,1,0,9,5,5,3,2]
out =np.zeros(10)
```

Running a loop to evaluate each function row separately f1 = s+t , f2 = s, . .

```
for j in range(10):
    f_vector_j = f_vector[j]
    out[j] = f_vector_j.subs( parameter_vector , parameter_values_vector )
print(out)
```

This code gives me error: `TypeError: can't convert expression to float`

Thanks in Advance

Comment: collect those `subs` results in a list, not a float dtype array.

Comment: I tried running you code, but the variable names in the loop differ from the ones in the setup.  I could edit them, but why should I do that work!  If you want help, write a clean questions!

Answer (score 2):

In SymPy you can use `lambdify`:

```
>>> from sympy import lambdify
>>> v,s,e = parameter_values_vector, parameter_vector, f_vector 
>>> f = lambdify(s, e)
>>> f(*v)
[5, 2, 4, -1, 0, 5, 9, -5, -2, 3]
>>> [i.subs(dict(zip(s, v))) for i in e]
[5, 2, 4, -1, 0, 5, 9, -5, -2, 3]
```

In the upcoming 1.9 version of SymPy `lambdify` will also allow you to have repeated expressions extracted transparently (inside `lambdify`) which will make the computation more efficient if there are repeated sub-expressions within `f_vector`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Appreciate the two different methods you showed.

Answer (score 0):

Your loop, collecting values in a list (so there's no constraint on what they can be):

```
In [21]: out=[]
    ...: for j in range(10):
    ...:     fj = f_vector[j]
    ...:     out.append(fj.subs( parameter_vector,parameter_values_vector ))
    ...: 

In [22]: out
Out[22]: [s + t, s, v - 2, -a + w, q, r, e, a - 7, b - m, t]
```

`subs` hasn't changed anything.

But if I use `zip` to pair old and new values as `subs` expects:

```
In [23]: out=[]
    ...: for j in range(10):
    ...:     fj = f_vector[j]
    ...:     out.append(fj.subs(zip( parameter_vector,parameter_values_vector )))
    ...: 

In [24]: out
Out[24]: [5, 2, 4, -1, 0, 5, 9, -5, -2, 3]
```

That `zip` does:

```
In [25]: list(zip( parameter_vector,parameter_values_vector ))
Out[25]: 
[(s, 2),
 (t, 3),
 (v, 6),
 (w, 1),
 (q, 0),
 (e, 9),
 (r, 5),
 (m, 5),
 (b, 3),
 (a, 2)]
```

This is basic debugging that you should have done yourself.

You could have tested the `subs` on a single term of the `f_vector`.  Making sure individual pieces of the code work is a key part of debugging.

```
In [31]: fj.subs(parameter_vector, parameter_values_vector)
Out[31]: t

In [32]: fj.subs(t,3)
Out[32]: 3
```

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience caused due to wrong code in question. I will definitely apply the method of debugging you mentioned. Just starting out coding, i guess i have a long way to go.  Thanks for such detailed answer.